# Is there any reason to use MOVS/CMPS/STOS/SCAS without a repeat prefix?

Tags: assembly, x86

The x86 architecture allows string instructions to be used with or without a repeat prefix. But  they don't seem to do anything interesting without the repeat prefix. MOVS without REP, for example, can be replaced with a simple MOV.

Is there a good reason to use MOVS (and STOS, SCAS, CMPS) without REP? Or is this just a useless idiosyncrasy of the x86 instruction set?

Comment: Wrong, the replacement for `MOVS` is 2 `MOV` instructions (through a register!) and 2 increments/decrements.

Comment: @Jester It's also possible that you don't have any free registers when doing `movs`, in that case you would need to `push reg`, `mov reg,[si/esi]`, `mov [di/edi],reg`, `pop reg`, or alternatively `push word/dword [si/esi]`, `pop word/dword [di/edi]`. The same applies to `cmps`, except that **to replace `cmps` you do need a free register** to do `mov reg,[si/esi]`, `cmp reg,[di/edi]`. If you don't have a free register and you want to replace `cmps`, you need to `push reg`, `mov reg,[si/esi]`, `cmp reg,[di/edi]`, `pop reg`. `movs` and `cmps` also need increments to `si`/`esi` and `di`/`edi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Not necessarily on purpose, yet you can use them for some sort of optimization.

It is, for example, faster (provided that rsi, rsi point to the right location) to use `movs` than

```
mov rax,[whatever1]
mov [whatever2],rax
```

For the rest, I'm not sure at the moment, but the execution times could be looked up I guess.
Incrementing/decrementing `rsi, rdi` would be a side effect here actually.

Also, printing a C style string in low level mode (no formatting or special chars; direct video memory access) is like:

```
    ; ...
_load_char:
    lodsb
    or al,al
    jz _end_of_string
    stosw
    jmp _load_char
_end_of_string:
    ; ...
```

Here you need to examine each single character you load and determine if the end of the string was reached or not so you cannot use `rep`. Though one might think of `repz movsb` that won't work here, since one of two consecutive bytes in the video mem is the attribute byte for the particular character. In this case it is an intended feature.

Comment: Oh I like your Low Level Video example -- it must be *decades* I last used that, but it sure was fast. Wasn't there an optimization, though, where one used `scasb` to find the length and then use `jcxz`? (It'd still need 'manual' `stosw`.)

Comment: @Jongware I have to admit, I don't really remember. It has been quite some years since I've used ASM for anything serious, let alone DOS applications or OS programming. I guess some kind of benchmark would give a better reply than myself. Prediction capabilites of today's CPUs might make those results invalid across different chips though.

Comment: I wonder if `test al,al` could be theoretically faster than `or al,al` on modern processors here. `test al,al` does not create a register dependency.

Comment: @nrz Yes, you're right, but I didn't want to edit the answer just for a simple optimization bit, since the above piece of code is for demonstrating how `lod*` may be used without `rep` rather than production. :) Nah, okay, I'm lazy.